# Processing language on Atom

Tags: command, processing, atom-editor

I've recently started learning the Processing for one of my courses, and whilst I've had success in it, this one program seems to allude me. I wanted to practise drawing shapes off-screen, and then call them using the drawShape command. But obviously, that was completely wrong. When I run the HTML file that is linked to my source code, all I get is a blank screen. Note the problem is not that the file is incapable of running, I've had already made plenty of programs, but it seems this time I put in an unknown variable or command and I really don't have the experience to know what I did wrong.

```js
// defines the color of construction
colour inside = color(0);
// defines the location of the construction
var x_pos = 0;
var y_pos = 0;
// defines the width of the construction
var totalWidth = 500;
var roofWidth = 200;
var doorWidth = totalWidth - 300;
var windowWidth = totalWidth - 320;
// defines the height of the construction
var totalHeight = 200;
var roofHeight = totalHeight-50;
var doorHeight = 0;
var windowWidth = 0;
function setup() {
  // put setup code here
    createCanvas(800,600);
    background(0);
  // defines the main body of the house & draws it of screen
  body = createShape(rect, x_pos,y_pos,totalWidth,totalHeight)
  square.setFill(inside);
  square.setStroke(false);
  endShape(CLOSE);
}

function draw() {
  // put drawing code here
  fill(0);
  shape(body,x_pos,y_pos);
  rect(x_pos,y_pos,totalWidth,totalHeight);
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but did you mean to have a space between colour and inside on line 2? I don't know much at all about processing, but that would be a syntax error in most languages I am familiar with.

Comment: You have at least one syntax error with `colour inside` which needs to be `var colour_inside` or something: notice the `var` keyword for declaring a variable, and notice no spaces in the variable name. Then I'm not sure the `color()` function will work before `setup()` is called. You need to check your [developer tools](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) for errors and try to isolate the problem a little better. Which line of code is causing the problem? Start over with a blank sketch and add one line at a time until it stops working.